# JSON dict objects not having key, val pairing in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm new to working with JSON in python3 and have run into an issue that I couldn't find on SO or google anywhere.I have a program that reads in a JSON file that is formulated as such:

```
[
{
    "message": {
        "Y": "15",
        "datetime": "2016-05-31 09:00:00",
        "X": "174",
        "proxCard": "vlagos001",
        "type": "mobile-prox",
        "floor": "1"
    },
    "offset": 32400.0
},
{
    "message": {
        "Y": "15",
        "datetime": "2016-05-31 09:00:00",
        "X": "174",
        "proxCard": "vlagos001",
        "type": "mobile-prox",
        "floor": "1"
    },
    "offset": 32400.0
}, 
.
.
etc
]
```

My program reads in the file, calls `json.load()` on it, and then attempts to go through each item and grab certain variables and later operate on them. However I am having a tough time working with the file and ran into something that I don't understand when checking the types of each var.

The following code is used to get each type of item.

```
input = open(file)
data = json.load(input)
print(type(data)) #returns <class 'list'>
for obj in data:
    print(type(obj))  #returns <class 'dict'>
    print(obj)
    for key in obj:
        print(type(key))  #returns <class 'str'>
        print(key)
    break
```

Run through once, the above code returns:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>
{'offset': 32400.0, 'message': {'floor': '1', 'type': 'mobile-prox', 'datetime': '2016-05-31 09:00:00', 'X': '174', 'proxCard': 'vlagos001', 'Y': '15'}}
<class 'str'>
offset
<class 'str'>
message
```

As you can see, the `data` var is a list of `dicts`. But when I try to grab the key and value pairs from each object like so:

```
for obj in data:
    print(type(obj))  #returns <class 'dict'>
    print(obj)
    for key, val in obj:
        print(type(key))
        print(type(val))
        print(key)
        print(val)
     break
```

I get an error saying it cant unpack the values, as if it weren't a dict:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>
{'message': {'type': 'mobile-prox', 'proxCard': 'vlagos001', 'X': '174', 'floor': '1', 'datetime': '2016-05-31 09:00:00', 'Y': '15'}, 'offset': 32400.0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_analysis.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "data_analysis.py", line 82, in main
    AnalyzeMobileProx(data)
  File "data_analysis.py", line 17, in AnalyzeMobileProx
    for key, val in obj:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Could anyone explain why this is? From my understanding, each object is seen as a dict and should have a `key, val` pair, one key being "message" and one being "offset", with "message" being a dict on its own in which I can access the values. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to use `for key, value in obj.items()`

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anyhting to do with JSON. `dict`s deserialized from JSON text are just normal python `dict`, not some special "json dicts".